# Spawn filled with lava (2B2T)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a bed in 2B2T, set my spawn, and then died.
Meanwhile someone came along and trapped my spawnpoint with obsidian and covered it with lava.
I have no items and no way to edit the world/my gamemode.
When I respawned I was trapped in an endless loop of dying

How do I escape!?

Answer (score 4):

## Break the bed.

There is a small invulnerability timer after you respawn, which is enough to break the bed. After you die the next time (which is pretty soon thanks to the lava), you will respawn at the world spawn point.

Answer (score 1):

Try to find someone on the server willing to break the obsidian and then your bed. Once your bed is broken, you should respawn back at spawn (which probably is only a minor improvement from what I can read about the server).

Comment: Oh wow, since this was posted, I watched a video about this server and yes, it's not a nice fate to have your bed blocked there. The spawn chunks are absolute, deadly chaos.